# ffmpeg sepia effect on video

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing

How can I apply simple sepia effect of a video using FFmpeg ? I am seeking for a single line FFmpeg command which I will be using in android.Though I have learnt `colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131` on official FFmpeg doc , but unable to apply it properly.Thank you.

Comment: See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/926617/ffmpeg-applying-effects-to-a-video). And [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/#sepiaEquivalent) is the sepia matrix. So according to those, FFmpeg doc example is correct. What do you exactly mean by "unable to apply it properly" ? And workaround you tried ?

Comment: Thanks for that.Can you please reply how to enable filter in ffmpeg as I am getting No such filter:"*" .

Comment: You need to include full FFmpeg command you are using. Probably your command filter may include a weird character.

Comment: Well my command is
 ffmpeg -i /sdcard/test.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a libfaac -filter_complex "[0:v]eq=1.0:0:1.3:2.4:0.175686275:0.103529412:0.031372549:0.4[outv]" -map [outv] /sdcard/testgrayscale.mp4
Where should I add filter  command here? Thank you .

Answer (score 8):

You just need to chain the filters appropriately. But in your approach, using `eq` filter may be difficult to implement the sepia matrix with FFmpeg as it has an associated matrix. Instead I suggest you an easy way with [`colorchannelmixer`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#colorchannelmixer).

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -filter_complex "
[0:v]colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131[colorchannelmixed];
[colorchannelmixed]eq=1.0:0:1.3:2.4:1.0:1.0:1.0:1.0[color_effect]" -map [color_effect] -c:v libx264 -c:a copy output_video
```

Here sepia is implemented using `colorchannelmixer` filter and it is followed by the [`eq`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq) filter to adjust the brightness, contrast, etc. of the video while keeping rgb colour values to their default `1`.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for that but still its giving error
 No such filter: 'eq'
 Error configuring filters.

Comment: can you please post the complete uncut output for this command. ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/))

Comment: There is an error in the command you are using. You use `color-effect` instead of `color_effect`. But that is not the cause for this error. I'm not familiar with this error. But what I'm guessing is the version you are trying is 2.4.2 and `eq` filter may be available there with a difference face. See [here](https://wjwoodrow.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/adjusting-video-contrast-brightness-saturation-and-color-balance-with-ffmpeg/).

Comment: @Chamath +1 for this ans. I want soft effect over video. Do you have idea for soft effect ?

Comment: Video gets edited , but with no audio, @Chamath Can you please update your answer, so that the output will be with audio