# Adding Video Visual Filter to mp4

Tags: android, video, filter, effects

I am trying to add `visual filters` to `video` in `Android`. It should look like something Instagram has, that after recording a `video`, you can choose a `visual filter` from the list and then apply it. So far the best I have found is `GPUImage` that has multiple filter option but it can only be used on images.

After recording video, I create a `.mp4` file into `temp` folder and before uploading it, similar screen to the picture below opens up. And I would need to create a similar filter option and filter addition.

[image]

Is there some `API` available that could help me or does someone have a source code?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20714782/6211906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while but I figured it out using `FFmpeg`. Sine my project was already using `bravobit FFmpeg` ([Bravobit ffmpeg](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android)) I decided to stick with it. I have addded all the code it took me to create this just in case someone tumbles at the same place.

First I had to make a `Horizontal scrollview`:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="143dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/filter_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And create a `filter_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="95dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter_item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14dp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/filter_item_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/filter_item_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Next I get a thumbnail from my video `File` and call a method using that thumbnail:

```
shareToFragment.setThumbNailImage(getVideoThumbnail(cameraOutputFile.getPath()));

public static Bitmap getVideoThumbnail(String path) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever fmmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();

    try {
        fmmr.setDataSource(path);

        final byte[] data = fmmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

        if (data != null) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        }

        if (bitmap == null) {
            bitmap = fmmr.getFrameAtTime();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        bitmap = null;
    } finally {
        fmmr.release();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

And now finally the code for creating and using the filters:

```
String[] filters = new String[] {"colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131",  "curves=vintage", "curves=negative", "hue=s=0"};
String[] filterNames = new String[] {"Sepia",  "Vintage", "Negative", "Black/White"};
int loopCounter;

public void setThumbNailImage(Bitmap image) {
    loopCounter = -1;
    mGallery.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

    ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);

    createNewFileForImageAndVideoNoFilter();
    bitmapToFile(image);

    addFilter(mInflater);

}

private void addFilter(LayoutInflater mInflater){
    loopCounter++;
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_item,
            mGallery, false);

    createNewFileForFilteredImage();



    String[] cmd = { "-i",  imageToBeFiltered.toString(), "-filter_complex", filters[loopCounter], imageWithFilter.toString()};

    ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String message) {
            super.onSuccess(message);

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageWithFilter.getAbsolutePath());
            ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_item_image);
            img.setImageBitmap(image);
            mGallery.addView(view);
            TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.filter_item_name);
            txt.setText(filterNames[loopCounter]);
            view.setId(loopCounter);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    filteredVideo.delete();
                    String[] cmd = { "-i",  originalVideoFile.toString(), "-filter_complex", filters[view.getId()], "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",  filteredVideo.toString()};
                    ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String message) {
                            super.onSuccess(message);
                            System.out.println("ffmpegVideo: succ" + message);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Done with adding flter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            somethingYouWannaDoWithTheOutputFile();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(String message) {
                            super.onFailure(message);
                            System.out.println("ffmpegVideo: faill" + message);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(String message) {
                            super.onProgress(message);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Adding filter", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

            if (loopCounter+1 < filters.length) addFilter(mInflater);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(String message) {
            super.onFailure(message);
            if (loopCounter+1 < filters.length) addFilter(mInflater);
        }
    });
}


public void createNewFileForImageAndVideoNoFilter(){
    filteredVideo = new File(context.getFilesDir()+ Common.TEMP_LOCAL_DIR + "/" + "filteredVideo.mp4");
    imageToBeFiltered = new File(context.getFilesDir()+ Common.TEMP_LOCAL_DIR + "/" + "_imageToBeFiltered.png");
    if(filteredVideo.exists()){
        filteredVideo.delete();
        imageToBeFiltered.delete();
    }
}

private void bitmapToFile(Bitmap bitmap){
    try {
        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(imageToBeFiltered));
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, os);
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void createNewFileForFilteredImage(){
    imageWithFilter = new File(context.getFilesDir()+ Common.TEMP_LOCAL_DIR + "/" + "_filteredImage.png");
    if(imageWithFilter.exists()){
        imageWithFilter.delete();
    }
}
```

At first I got corrupted `.mp4` because I wasn't adding `"-pix_fmt", "yuv420p"`. You can read more about it here : [FFmpeg video filters corrupt mp4 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295933/ffmpeg-video-filters-corrupt-mp4-file)

Answer (score 1):

You have to re-encode the mp4 file in order to apply the filter to every frame. I can think of two ways of doing that, but they require advanced programming skills. The easiest way I think is FFMPEG (make sure to check the licenses if you want to re-encode). [This link](https://medium.com/@ilja.kosynkin/building-ffmpeg-for-android-607222677a9e) might help you to compile it for Android. Once that's done, check out the the FFMPEG documentation and forums for filters and overlays. The other (free) way is using `MediaCodec` to re-encode your video, and use GL shaders to manipulate your frames. [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) is a project that may provide you with the necessary tools for this. Also, there might be pre-built libraries of both ways on the internet, make sure to use the given information to do your research first.

Comment: I am already using FFMPEG to convert from pcm to WAV, and I have seen some methods that allow some basic filters, but the harder part is the list which you can scroll (as shown on the picture) and select filter and then apply it.

Comment: You should be able to grab any frame from your video, apply the filter to the image and show it in your UI. Unfortunately, I cant give you any code examples, but FFMPEG is capable of doing this.

Comment: I will look into this

Comment: Is there any direct link to where I can find FFmpeg Visual Filters?
All I can find are just cropping and editing filters

Comment: Try to search for the common effect types on the internet. Here is a link for sepia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30972646/ffmpeg-sepia-effect-on-video . But you might want to use "fish-eye" or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this one](https://github.com/bhuvnesh123/FFmpeg-Video-Editor-Android) ? it uses FFMPEG to add filters / crop and more editing features, this can help you as a library and can give you an idea as well, it has a demo app built with this library available at [play store here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=videoeditor.bhuvnesh.com.ffmpegvideoeditor)

Comment: Do you have any examples how I can save an output mp4 File saved in the `temp` folder for example with added filter?
Because I do not quite understand their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Alongside the FFMPEG ways, the one I found useful for myself is to use [GLSurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView). The idea is to render the video on the GLSurfaceView and render the filters using openGL. Check out [this project](https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects).

Comment: Is it possible to save the output File to external memory, with added filter?

Comment: Yup, go through the grafika projects, particularly [this one](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/grafika/RecordFBOActivity.java)