# FFmpeg video filters corrupt mp4 file

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to add visual filters to `mp4` files using `FFmpeg`.

I have tried many filters, but 4 of them worked out of which only 1 worked worked perfectly. I am using them in an `Android application`, but I tried the same command lines on `windows cmd` using `FFmpeg` and the result is same. With 3 filters the `.mp4` is unplayable by many players and also `Androids mediaplayer`. I can still play the "corrupt" files on `VLC` and players that have many codex`s, but I need them to work perfectly.

The only filter working as intended is `Black and White` and the command is (have tried both `-vf` and `-filter_complex`):

```
-i origin.mp4 -filter_complex hue=s=0 blackWhite.mp4
```

The other 3 are `Sepia`, `Vintage` and `Negative`

```
"colorchannelmixer=.393:.769:.189:0:.349:.686:.168:0:.272:.534:.131",  "curves=vintage", "curves=negative"
```

Since I cannot upload video files here, I have added a link of 3 files, the original video file, black/white filtered file (that works), vintage file (that does not work).

[Dropbox - video files link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/taxrkwp2jkucpaa/AABeCbFtpLeL_9iZj_gpJTWKa?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curves and colorchannelmixer filters only work on RGB pixels so FFmpeg converts the video beforehand, if required.

When saving to MP4 using a typical H.264 encoder, ffmpeg will convert to YUV color encoding but pick the highest fidelity pixel format which, for a RGB source, is YUV 4:4:4. This format is not compatible with most players. Solution is to manually force YUV 4:2:0 output. Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` just before the output filename.

Comment: Or append `format=yuv420p` to the end of your filterchain. I generally prefer to keep all of the filtering within the filterchain instead of using the legacy `-pix_fmt` option.